# Difference between "Done" and "Cancel" in Export for Web

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, save

In both **Illustrator** and **Photoshop**, the **Export for Web** window has three options at the bottom:

[image]

*Done, Cancel and Save*

Save will save the image for Web with the settings that you have selected.

However, **Done** and **Cancel** seem to do exactly the same thing: close the window without performing any saving action.

***Why are there two options that seem to do the same thing?***

Answer (score 3):

Done - This option will remember the current settings.

Cancel - Resets the settings and closes the dialog.

Source:

Just hover over the buttons and a tooltip will popup.

Comment: To which default settings does Cancel reset the settings? This seems inconsistent with every other dialog box in History

Comment: @MicroMachine Because exporting to web remembers the previous settings you exported with. 

It's a feature to allow you to quickly export via the export as command.

Comment: Usually export dialogs will always remember your settings. If I click on Cancel it still remembers some settings the one time after, though.

Comment: @MicroMachine Every time you Export/Save for web the settings get stored internally with the image. `Cancel` will leave those stored settings as they are and exit the dialog. `Done` will *update* those stored settings to the current settings and exit the dialog window. There's really only a difference if you changed something and then click `Done`.

Comment: I encourage contributors to do the following: Open an image, Save for Web, Change Image Size to 50%, click Done, reopen Save for Web window, notice the percentage is back to 100%. Some settings will NOT be saved when clicking Done. I just tested this today on PS CC 2018 and Illustrator CC 2018... Therefore, I would like a detailed answer explaining what "Done" does and doesn't do, not what it's supposed to do.